# Three dots in the middle (...)

Tags: word-choice, nuances

"両方…だ" , "両方…やるぞ"

The speaker pauses before the words of affirmation,would you say it's because he doesn't really want to do "both" ?

( context: the speaker is at a deadend and has to make an uncomfortable choice)

Comment: [Details, please.](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2189/what-should-i-do-if-i-was-asked-for-the-context-why-is-it-important) This can't be answered without context. Questions that only solicit speculative responses are off-topic, across the SE network.

Answer (score 1):

These dots do represent a pause, but you cannot tell why they're there without the full understanding of the context. What kind of character is he? Often the reason can be simply "he is a person who speaks slowly." Assuming he usually speaks normal Japanese and the context you provided is correct, "he hesitated while saying this" is a plausible reason.